# Cant fix npm permissions mac mojave

Tags: node.js, npm

I have spent the last few hours trying every tutorial out there on how to fix npm permissions on a mac.

NOTHING has worked thus far.

Steps I have taken

I have uninstalled node multiple times, tried running brew `install node --without-npm` then installing npm seperately.

I have tried to create my own npm-package file in my root directory and change the npm source and still that doesnt work.

I have tried what is detailed here https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

I have tried what is shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxvybxYFq2o&t=154s

I have also tried a few other techniques all similar to above but nothing has worked.

Im on a 2015 macbook running a fresh install 0SX Mojave.

Any time I try to install a package it errors, and even if I use sudo, npm cant find the commands I'm entering for example if I

`sudo npm install @angular/cli` then try and use `ng` I get the `command not found: ng`

Any help would be appreciated. This question will be updated with methods used as they are suggested. Let me know If you need any more information.

Comment: have you tried opening the terminal with root priviliges?

Comment: @DennisPatterson yes

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration :(

These steps worked for me (from https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.md):

1. check if you have ~/**.bash_profile** file (home directory). I didn't. So I had to create it myself with:

   > touch ~/.bash_profile
2. Get NVM by running:

   > curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.11/install.sh | bash
3. them run

   > export NVM_DIR="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME/:-$HOME/.}nvm"
   >   [ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
4. verify nvm installation by running (you might need to restart terminal window before)

   > nvm --version
5. Install node via nvm - run:

   > nvm install node

(if you get version warning/error just follow the instructions(I had to run `npm config delete prefix` and then again `nvm install node`))

6. Install CLI:

   > npm install -g @angular/cli
7. verify installation:

   > ng -v

Hope it helps!